# MonacaでWebSocketServerプラグインを有効にするとビルドエラーが発生する

Tags: monaca

MonacaでCordva3.5.1のWebSocketServerプラグインを有効にし、Androidアプリのビルドをすると下記のエラーが発生します。

同じCordva3.5.1のHttpServerを有効にした場合にも同様のエラーが発生しましたが、Shareを有効にした場合には問題ありませんでした。
WebSocketServerやHttpServerを使う場合には何か他に設定が必要なのでしょうか？

---

> Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/eec3fd17f324a81a
>   Downloading project
>   Download complete
>   Running for 3.5
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" for android
>   cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/eec3fd17f324a81a/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version" ), continuing.
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.WebSocketServer" for android
>   cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/eec3fd17f324a81a/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version" ), continuing.
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" for android
>   Plugin "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" already installed on android.
>   Plugin "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" already installed on android.
>   Fetching plugin "/data/monaca_build_module/plugins/mobi.monaca.plugins.WebSocketServer@1.0.0" via plugin registry
>   Error: 404 Not Found: data
>       at RegClient.<anonymous> (/data/monaca_build_module/3.5/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
>       at Request.self.callback (/data/monaca_build_module/3.5/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Request.<anonymous> (/data/monaca_build_module/3.5/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/data/monaca_build_module/3.5/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:929:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
>   Build error: Error building project source code

AndroidManifest.xmlは以下の通りです

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="%%%VERSION_CODE%%%" android:versionName="%%%VERSION_NAME%%%" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="%%%PACKAGE_NAME%%%" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="%%%APPLICATION_NAME%%%">
     <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="%%%APPLICATION_NAME%%%" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Monacaを使うのが初めてなもので初歩的なミスだとしたら申し訳ありませんが、ご指導をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

同じ現象に悩まされています。私は、Shareを有効にしても失敗します。
アプリの実行で、plugins.httpServer(); が、Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'httpServer' とコンソールに出力されてHTTPサーバーを起動することができません。
USBデバッグしてみると、たしかに、plugins には、httpServer が含まれていません。
別のプラグイン DatePicker を有効にしてデバッグしてみると、plugins には、datePicker が含まれています。
どうやったら、httpServer が使えるようになるのか、私も知りたいです。